# Confusing syntax in Java

Tags: java, syntax, constructor, linked-list, simplify

I have a piece of code that I'm struggling to comprehend. The code snippet itself is a constructor for a doubly linked list, which is fine; however, the last line says:

`(head = head.next).previous = null;`

This supposedly removes the temporary node that is used to add the nodes from the array `a`. But how does it work? If someone could break it down into clear, separate lines, that would be very helpful.

Here is the constructor:

```
// standard constructor
public DoublyLinkedList() {
    head = tail = null;
    numElements = 0;
    changes = 0;
}

// constructor
public DoublyLinkedList(T[] a) {
    this();  // call the standard constructor

    Objects.requireNonNull(a, "a is null!");

    head = tail = new Node<>(null);  // a temporary node

    for (T value : a) {
        if (value != null) {
            tail = tail.next = new Node<>(value, tail, null);  // new node at the back
            numElements++;
      }
    }

    // remove the temporary node
    if (numElements == 0) head = tail = null;
    else (head = head.next).previous = null; // the problematic bit
}
```

Comment: Is this a logic question or a syntax question? What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: @shmosel I guess it is more of a syntax problem, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It goes like this:

```
if (numElements == 0) {
     head = null;
     tail = null;
}
else {
    head = head.next;
    head.previous = null; // the problematic bit
}
```

people should not write the original way, it makes the code confusing, as you just discovered.

Answer (score 0):

```
head = head.next;
head.previous = null;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Let me try and break it down for you. I am assuming that the part of the code that you are having difficulty understanding is the following:

```
else (head = head.next).previous = null; // the problematic bit
```

The expression inside of the brackets is evaluated first, meaning that the piece of code above essentially becomes the following, as other people before me have already mentioned.

```
head = head.next; // move onto the next node
head.previous = null;
```

If you are having difficulty comprehending the logic above, try running the following code below. The 4 + 2 is evaluated first before the division operation.

```
System.out.println((4 + 2) / 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The temporary node is needed to use `.next` at first time. It's put on the head. Then when it's no longer needed it's removed from head.

The problem in the code that `.previous` doesn't work there because it's not set in the loop.